# How to replace "$" sign from any string with something else in PHP?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am working with a wordpress project. where using some money related work. where amount in database.the amount shows with a $ sign. i want to replace this `$` sign with EURO sign. but when i using `str_replace` function it took the `$amount` as a variable, not as a string. what is the way to replace this $ ?

Here `echo product_list_price($project->ID);` function returning the price containing `$` sign. now i have to replace this sign into EURO sign and then to echo.
how can i convert this as a single quoted string?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Encapsulate the string in single quotes, not double...or show your code so we can see what you are doing.

Comment: Put your string inside single quotes.

Comment: Post your code what you have tried

Comment: example of your text ?

Comment: share you code what you did

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$euroPrice = str_replace('$', '€', $dollarPrice);`

As mentioned here, PHP tries to interpret words starting with `$` inside double-quoted strings as variables.

Answer (score 1):

The works fine, `str_replcae` will give you new modified string that you need to store, the old one will not be modified

```
    <?php
$money="44$";
$money2='44$';
$m1 = str_replace("$","€",$money);
$m2 =str_replace("$","€",$money2);
$m3 = str_replace('$','€',$money2);
echo $money." ".$money2." ";
echo $m1." ".$m2." ".$m3;
?>
```

output:

```
44$ 44$ 44€ 44€ 44€
```

Comment: Its not working brother. as the amount is return of function .

Comment: liked i show the proper running example with output , so must be doing something else so we need to take a look what actually you are trying to achieve or there could be some compatible code or bug something.